# How can I prevent additional strings from being added after URLs that end with .php?

Tags: php, url

our website's team just discovered that any user can add a slash '/' then any string after a URL that ends with a .php extension and still access the same original page.

For example:
I can access www.mydomain.com/index.php with:

- www.mydomain.com/index.php/test
- www.mydomain.com/index.php/test/123
- www.mydomain.com/index.php/wqeqwew/2234dwd

(Note: Additional strings after index.php/ are non-existent in the server, they're just some garbage)

Another problem is that with my dynamic URLs, I can always add a nonexistent php file in between my domain name and the first parameter.

For example:
I can access www.mydomain.com/product/one with:

- www.mydomain.com/test.php/product/one
- www.mydomain.com/imnothere.php/product/one

How can I prevent this from happening and how do I deal with it? Is this a serious problem in terms of SEO or security? I want the website to return 404 error whenever these kinds of URL are entered or clicked in the browser.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I think I already fixed it. For the first problem, I added `AcceptPathInfo Off` in my .htaccess. And for the second problem, I just added `^` before my RewriteRule for my dynamic URL, e.g. `RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$` so that nobody can add anymore extra string in between the domain name and the first parameter.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Show us Your `mod_rewrite` rules (.htaccess file).

Comment: I can kind a see why you would be worried. But this definitely is neither a security issue, nor does it anything for your SEO. The only way that it could possibly do something for your SEO, is if someone posted with  a link somewhere with some arbitrary keywords in url, but this is kinda out of your control anyway. And as for security, unless your script expects them params, there is hardly they can do anything :)

Comment: I could think of an exploit when this could be misused. Let's assume that some of Your scripts parses the URL and do something with its parts. Then there is at least a possibility of XSS attack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I prevent this from happening and how do I deal with it?

This is due to Apache's [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) directive. You can turn it off - if the server is configured accordingly, you'll just need a .htaccess file for it.

> Is this a serious problem in terms of SEO or security?

I can't think of a way in which it could be a serious problem. It's generally enabled by default in most handlers, and is being routinely used as a "poor man's `mod_rewrite`" (A way to provide fancy-looking URLs).

Comment: SEO - and what about a **duplicit** (multiplicit) content? Though these nonexistent URLs probably won't be found within the content there still is a possibility of a mistake done when creating the content while a wrong (but mistakenly working) link got indexed...

Comment: @shadyyx It's a possible problem, but I doubt that Google isn't aware of this feature and doesn't punish content duplication if it's caused by external links.

Comment: Thanks, @Pekka for your reply.  Do I just add `AcceptPathInfo Off` somewhere in my .htaccess file? I tried doing that but nothing has happened. Thanks again!

Comment: @jcap yeah, that's the idea... If it doesn't work, the possibility to change those options in .htaccess may be disabled in the server configuration. In that case, you would have to talk to the server admin. Another option would be to exit the script and send a `404` header if `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]` is set - but you'd have to do that for every PHP file separately

Comment: @Pekka, I got it now. It didn't work because of the RewriteRule I added to allow removal of .php extension from my URL. I removed it and  and the `AcceptPathInfo Off` worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```