# 404 page not working for links with trailing slash

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a site with a 404 error page, set up in htaccess like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/error404.php
```

This works fine if you try to access a page that doesnt exist:

```
www.example.com/nonsensepage.php
www.example.com/nonsensepage.htm
```

But Google search has some old links from the previous site (a Joomla site), that have the following format:

```
www.example.com/index.php/news
```

And this isnt caught by my 404 page. Instead it goes to my index page and breaks the page!

How can I make sure that my 404 page catches ALL wrong URLs?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

I have already tried the duplicate question answer, (to add AcceptPathInfo Off) but it doesnt seem to work for me.

This is everything I have in my htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

AcceptPathInfo Off
CheckSpelling Off

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
 ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
 </IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

FileETag none
ServerSignature Off

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/error404.php
```

I would also be happy with just a solution that strips any trailing content and slashes, always directing:

```
index.php/anything
```

to either index.php or error404.php

Comment: Does your application return 404 when you call that old URL `www.example.com/index.php/news`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent additional strings from being added after URLs that end with .php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525812/how-can-i-prevent-additional-strings-from-being-added-after-urls-that-end-with)

Comment: here is an good introduction how to [Setting a 404 error page via .htaccess](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/how-to/setting-a-404-error-page-via-htaccess) hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this line at top of your .htaccess to send 404 for anything after a slash for `.php` files:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

**Alternatively** you can use this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.php/.+$ [L,NC,R=404]
```

Comment: That works perfectly fine on my Apache. You might be having some misconfiguration issue

Comment: also try my alternate solution.